# css js file are not displaying in laravel5

Tags: laravel

I've just installed a Laravel 5 project on XAMPP and my pages are not finding the css files.

This is the link to my css in my public folder:

```
{{ URL::asset('codepath') }}

{!! ('codepath') !!}
```

Comment: what are the errors you see on inspect? check `{{ URL::asset('codepath') }}` actuall value after compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Link to CSS should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("css/my.css") }}" />
```

To make it work, `my.css` file should be placed at `laravelProject\public\css\my.css`.

If this doesn't work, then you should setup XAMP properly and point web server to a `public` directory which is inside laravel project root.

Comment: or like this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('css/my.css") }}' />`

Answer (score 0):

Your link to CSS file should be like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("yourcssfile.css") }}" />
```

OR

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url("yourcssfile.css") }}" />
```

And your file should be in `public` directory of your project e.g `yourproject/public/yourcssfile.css`

That's it!